# Making a sub class of 'int' but still return 'int' in type

Tags: python, python-3.x, micropython

I am trying to add some functionality to the 'int' class in python. And I would like to be able to take type() or isinstance() of this subclass and still return it as an int so I can compare with values that are int's.

My code is as following

```
testValue = 5    # create int test value
bint      = int  # To save the reference, so I can call the correct int in my class below
class Integer(bint):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return_Value = bint(args[0])
        except:
            return_Value = bint(args[0], 16)
        finally:
            return super(Integer, cls).__new__(cls, return_Value)

int = Integer # Overwrite the buildin 'int' class
```

but if I call isinstance() on these names I do not get the same.

```
print(isinstance(testValue, bint))
print(isinstance(int, bint))
```

The two calls there return the following:

```
True
False
```

And if I use type()

```
print(type(testValue))
print(type(int))
```

I get

```
<class 'int'>
<class 'type'>
```

Is it not possible to mask a subclass so it returns its parent?

The reason for this is that in micropython 'int' does not take more than one argument, but executing the same code on pc the 'int' class needs info if it's to convert HEX or BIN string values. So to be able to run debugging locally I need to change the functionality of 'int'

**EDIT**

What I want to do is to make a type check on my 'testValue' which is of the class int. and compare it to 'int' which can be both the buildin 'int' class or my own subclass

```
if type(testValue) == int:
    pass
```

Regards

Comment: 1: you didn't return anything from `__new__`.
2: why did you think that type(int) will give you `Integer`? `int` is `Integer`, the `type` of `Integer` is `type`, as any other class in pyhon.

Comment: This is confusing. You keep using `int` as if it should be an instance of an integer, but it isn't: it's the *type* of integers. Why would you ever expect or want `isinstance(int, bint)` to be true?

Comment: A *class* is always of type `type`, and is never an *instance* of anything, because it's a *class*, not an *instance*. (Except, well, an instance of `type`, but let's not get too confused…)

Comment: @Jonathan1609, fixed i had delete this by mistake

Comment: @deceze yeah, missed that i can make it work using print(isinstance(int(0), bint)). Then I get the correct value. but is this the correct way to do it

Comment: Since your edit you're still confusing `int` with an integer. `type(int)` is `type` because `int` is a *type* not an integer. `type(testValue) == type(int)` would only be true if `testValue` was also a type.

Comment: Well, "correct" is… unclear. `int(0)` creates an *instance* of your custom `Integer` class, and that instance is an instance of `bint`, since `Integer` subclasses `bint`. So, yeah, that's "correct" as in "it works". Whether that's what you *want* to do I don't know.

Comment: @deceze. Well what i want is a way to compare "type(testValue) == int:" regardless of me using my subclass or the 'int' class it self

Comment: Then yes, if you have an *instance* of an int, e.g. `5` or `Integer(5)` or `int(5)`, those are all *instances of* `bint`. Note that `isinstance(5, int)` is false though, since `int` is your custom `Integer` and `5` is an instance of the original `builtin.int`.

Comment: @deceze, yes but then my question is. is there a way to make my 'int' look like 'int' when making the above compare. IE if type(TestValue) == 'int': ?

Comment: No. A numeric literal like `5` will always be a `builtin.int`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem. However, it's not totally ideal but it works.

using the following code

```
TestValue = 5

bint      = int

class Integer:

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return_Value = bint(args[0])
        except:
            return_Value = bint(args[0], 16)
        finally:
            return return_Value
              
int = Integer
```

I can get a successful comparison by using the following conditional

```
if type(TestValue) == type(int(0)):
    pass
```

This works both locally and in micropython.